# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'inference_mode'

Tags: pytorch

I am very new to `pytorch`, and when I try to run my `CNN`, I encountered the Error:

> AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'inference_mode'.*
> Does anyone know what is going one? It worked on Google colab but no where else.

Comment: Please provide the code segment which fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try bump the version to 1.13. Reference: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.inference_mode.html

Answer (score -1):

Most likely its a version issue.

`torch.inference_mode()` was added recently in `v1.9`. Make sure you have the correct version.

Try printing `torch.__version__` to check your version.

Comment: I had the issue still even with torch 1.9.0. I think I fixed it by updating `torchvision`

Comment: This did not fix the problem unfortunately! The error persists with 1.9.0